# Android Cast Dialog - Pause working, play is not

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

Having trouble with the cast dialog and a custom receiver. Media is cast and playing, the cast dialog shows the pause icon and hitting pause causes the cast framework to send a message to the receiver which comes through to `cast.receiver.MediaManager.onPause()`. From there I pause my custom player and call `MediaManager.broadcastStatus()` which results in the sender's cast dialog button switching from the pause icon to the play icon. However, pressing the play button does nothing. Debugging the Android client I see that `MediaSessionCompatApi21.onPause()` and `.onPlay()` are called upon pressing the button but only pause is sending anything to the receiver. Any idea why the framework is not causing the `cast.receiver.MediaManager.onPlay()` function to be called on the receiver? 
 
 This happens with `support:7.25.2 / play-services:10.2.0` or `support:7.24.4 / play-services:9.4.0`. I'm clearly not understanding something basic..

Another possibly related thing I noticed somewhat randomly, both on my app and the CastVideos-android app, is that commenting out the mediarouter compile line in the gradle file results in a runnable build but the cast dialog pause function is broken too. Everything else cast related works fine though. Painfully confusing..

UPDATE: I ran CastVideos-android app against my custom receiver (not playing any media but simulating the messaging) and the play/pause works fine. Starting to believe this is a build issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking more closely at the latest CastVideos-android sample solved the problem. Given a dummy MediaInfo instance X, I was calling

`_remoteMediaClient.load(X);`

Seemed pretty reasonable but it wasn't working for the cast dialog play problem. Using MediaQueueItem (*from looking at the latest CastVideos-android version*) fixed it...

`MediaQueueItem qi = new MediaQueueItem.Builder(X).setAutoplay(true).setPreloadTime(20).build();
MediaQueueItem[] qa = new MediaQueueItem[]{qi};                     _remoteMediaClient.queueLoad(qa,0,MediaStatus.REPEAT_MODE_REPEAT_OFF, null);`